# How to use $layout in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I try to use the `$layout` property in my controllers, but I always get the following error:

> Call to a member function nest() on a non-object

When `dd()` the value of `this->layout`, it seems like it is only a string.

Here's my code:

**base.php**

```
class Base_Controller extends Controller {
  public $layout = 'layouts.common';
}
```

**admin.php**

```
class Admin_Controller extends Base_Controller {
  public function action_index() {
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'admin.home');
  }
}
```

I probably miss something, but I can't find it in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, just found the trouble. I was ovewritting `__construct` to add filters, but wasn't calling the parent construct:

```
class Admin_Controller extends Base_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->filter('before', 'auth');
  }
  public function action_index() {
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'admin.home');
  }
}
```